# Hibernate ManyToMany same JoinColumn name

Tags: hibernate, orm, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-4.x

I have two entity classes `Activity` and `User`. The relationships between them are:

- One `Activity` can have one or many `User`
- One `User` can belongs to one or many `Activity`

So to achieve this I have defined `@ManyToMany` mapping between them. Below is my classes:

`Activity`:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "ACTIVITY")
public class Activity extends Entity {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4741665931936809028L;

    private Set<User> users;

    public Activity() {
        super();
    }

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = User.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "ACTIVITY_USER", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID"))
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

`User`:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User extends Entity {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -112950002831333869L;

    private Set<Activity> activities;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "users", targetEntity = Activity.class)
    public Set<Activity> getActivities() {
        return activities;
    }

    public void setActivities(Set<Activity> activities) {
        this.activities = activities;
    }
}
```

Both of the above classes extends `Entity`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Entity implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7470288121057059283L;

    private Long id;

    public Entity() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setLastUpdateTimestamp(Date lastUpdateTimestamp) {
        this.lastUpdateTimestamp = lastUpdateTimestamp;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        return prime * result + ((getId() == null) ? super.hashCode() : getId().hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!getClass().equals(HibernateProxyHelper.getClassWithoutInitializingProxy(obj))) {
            return false;
        }

        final Entity other = (Entity) obj;

        if (getId() != other.getId()) {
            if (getId() == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!getId().equals(other.getId())) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Now from:

```
@JoinTable(name = "ACTIVITY_USER", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID"))
```

what I understand that the name of the `@JoinColumn` of `joinColumns` takes the column name of the PK of one entity and the name of the `@JoinColumn` of `inverseJoinColumns` takes the column name of the PK of another entity. But in my case both of the column names are same, i.e., `ID` from the `Entity` class.

My question is how can I avoid this confliction of the column names? Any suggestion would be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes no sense to have two columns wit the same name in the same table. So just choose a different name for the columns.

Change

```
@JoinTable(name = "ACTIVITY_USER", 
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID"), 
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID"))
```

to

```
@JoinTable(name = "ACTIVITY_USER", 
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ACTIVITY_ID"), 
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
```

As the name of the attribute indicates, the name you give there is the name of the *join column*, part of the *join table*,  i.e. the name of the column holding the foreign key to the activity or user table, in the join table ACTIVITY_USER. Hibernate already know the name of the PK of User and Activity: you told it in their respective `@Id` annotation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation of the PK, I was wrong.